# How to Find a Backdoor in a Hacked WordPress Site with Debian

Tags: debian, php, mysql, wordpress

I think there was a backdoor created by the hacker which allowed them to bypass normal authentication.

- Wordpress 4.4.2 in apache2 with MySQL
- I install chkrootkit, rkhunter but finding nothing!
- I find in google http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-find-a-backdoor-in-a-hacked-wordpress-site-and-fix-it/ but without results.

Comment: You should nuke the Wordpress files from orbit.  Unless you can identify which backdoor was installed, this question, cannot be answered.

Comment: What a surprise. Wordpress gets hacked?! My advice, don't use Wordpress, just do it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't. If you think your system is compromised, it can *and probably is* compromised in a way that the exploit hides itself.

Flatten the machine and reinstall. It's (quite literally) the only way to be sure.

I'm serious. Don't spend more time looking for the rootkit. For all you know, that machine is being used to send spam from your domain (**or worse**) right now. Stop reading and go pull the plug.

Comment: Unless there is a rootkit installed on the CPU, sadly.. these are impossible to make these days :(